# ¿Cómo puedo vaciar un listView en C#?

Tags: c#

Necesito vaciar un listView porque cuando hago click en un botón, lleno el listView con los valores que recoge de la base de datos y no quiero que me los vuelva a repetir en el listView.

He estado viendo en foros que la gente comenta que es tuListView.Items.Clear() pero a mi no me funciona, me dice que Items no existe.

Este es el código que utilizo para agregar los valores al ListView que recibo de la base de datos

```
ListViewItem listView;
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS; database=base; Integrated Security=SSPI");
SqlCommand comandosql = new SqlCommand();
conexion.Open();

try
{
    comandosql.Connection = conexion;
    comandosql.CommandText = "SELECT dt1,dt2 FROM datos";
    SqlDataReader midatareader = comandosql.ExecuteReader();

    string valor1;
    string valor2;

    while (midatareader.Read())
    {
         valor1= midatareader.GetString(0);
         valor2= midatareader.GetString(1);
         listView = listViewBD.Items.Add(valor1);
         listView.SubItems.Add(valor2);
    }

         midatareader.Close();
         conexion.Close();
    }
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + err.Message);
}
```

Eso no tiene nada que ver con que no me funcione para vaciar el listView, no?

¿Alguno sabe alguna solución que si funcione?

No adjunto código porque pienso que no hace falta, pero si lo necesitáis, me lo decís y edito la pregunta.

Gracias

Comment: Con qué tecnología trabajas?

Comment: Perdona, a qué te refieres con qué tecnología trabajo. Estoy trabajando con C# y el Visual Studio. Espero a ver respondido a tu pregunta.

Comment: Si se que estás trabajando con C#, para eso son las etiquetas, me refiero a si estas usando Windows forms o WPF?

Comment: Es que si no me lo aclarabas mejor, no te entendía. Windows Forms.

Comment: De acuerdo. Sabrías ayudarme con lo que pido ahora que ya sabes las tecnologías con las que trabajo?

Comment: Tienes subitems dentro de los items del listview? Nos puedes mostrar como insertas datos en el listview? Probablemente tenga que hacer `Clear();` a cada uno de los subitems antes de hacer clear al principal.

Comment: Si, edito la pregunta.

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, espero que ahora sea de mayor ayuda.

Comment: Puedes probar a limpiar los `SubItems` de cada `Item` en el `ListView`? Yo no tengo acceso a un ordenador ahora mismo, pero debería funcionar.

Comment: `void Vaciar() { listView1.Items.Clear(); }`

Comment: Sii, es que me estaba confundiendo de coger el listView... vaya fallo más tonto estaba haciendo... Lo he solucionado ya, muchas gracias. Adjunto la solución que era como me habías dicho. `if (listViewBD.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    listViewBD.Items.Clear();
                }`

Comment: Gracias, pero ya encontré la solución. Estaba cogiendo otro nombre que no era del listView.

Answer (score 1):

```
    void Vaciar()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Sii, es que me estaba confundiendo de coger el listView... vaya fallo más tonto estaba haciendo... Lo he solucionado ya, muchas gracias. Adjunto la solución que era como me habías dicho. `if (listViewBD.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    listViewBD.Items.Clear();
                }`

Comment: Rodolfo, gracias por aportar. Sin embargo, para que la respuesta se considere de calidad, has de añadir una explicacion de cómo funciona o alguna referencia a la documentacion. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: no creo que esta repuesta requiera explicacion, el usuario tenia problemas por no sabre como se tenia que utilizar el clear de una listview, lo mas que podria agregar es que "tienes que limpiar la instancia de tu listview"